# Typo3 column width dissonance

Tags: css, html-table, typo3, width

I'm trying to troubleshoot some content my agency has on a site. Specifically, this:

http://tinypic.com/r/rwuul0/5

My concern is with that pesky column on the right with the contact information. It's not lining up, despite the markup being rigid (as far as I can tell). Trust me, I hate tables too, but we're also using the Typo3 CMS for the backend, and it insists on formatting all data as such:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="left:4px; border-collapse:collapse">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first_td">
        <p><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt;" lang="DE-CH">Bayer International SA</span></b></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="DE-CH">Badische   Bahnhofstrasse 16</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size: 10pt; " lang="DE-CH">CH-</span><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="DE-CH">8212 </span><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="DE-CH">Neuhausen am Rheinfall</span></p>
      </td>
      <td width="50" valign="top" style="width:49.6pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="EN-US">T</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="EN-US">F</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="EN-US">Website</span></p>
      </td>
      <td width="131" valign="top" style="width:131.4pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="EN-US">+41 52 674 99 36</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="EN-US">+41 52 670 05 59</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="EN-US"><a external="1" target="_blank" href="http://www.bayer.com/">www.bayer.com</a></span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Obnoxious, ain't it? That's the markup for the fourth entry that is returned from Typo3. Here's the markup for the fifth entry:

```
<table style="left:4px; border-collapse:collapse" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first_td">
        <p><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt;" lang="DE-CH">Constellium   Specialty Sheet</span></b></p>
        <p><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="DE-CH">Engineered   Products Switzerland Ltd.</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="DE-CH">Badische   Bahnhofstrasse 16</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="DE-CH">CH-8212 Neuhausen am Rheinfall</span></p>
        <p><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="DE-CH">&nbsp;</span></b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:49.6pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt" valign="top" width="50">
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt">&nbsp;</p>
        <p style="margin-right: 1.35pt; "><span style="font-size: 10pt; " lang="ES">T</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="ES">F </span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="ES">Website</span></p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:49.6pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt" valign="top" width="50">
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt">&nbsp;</p>
        <p style="margin-right: 1.35pt; "><span style="font-size: 10pt; " lang="ES">+41 52 674 91 11</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="ES">+41 52 674 96 01</span></p>
        <p style="margin-right:1.35pt"><span style="font-size:10.0pt" lang="ES"><a external="1" target="_blank" href="http://www.constellium.com/">www.constellium.com</a> </span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The class "first_td" is something that seems to be generated dynamically through Typo3, as the CSS is showing up on index.php. I've tried forcing the column width inline in `<td>`, but it's still coming out dissonant. Chrome's developer tools isn't any help either; it shows the proper CSS, but readily admits that the column width isn't what it should be.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something in the code that I'm not seeing, or does Typo3 throw a wrench into things? If you can think of anything, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Can you tell us, how do you organize that content? For each entry one content element using the RTE? You are using css_styled_content? There is no hard-coded markup in TYPO3, so it is in your hand how to render your output. So IMHO it is an TYPO3 configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, every entry is generated through the RTE. I am not sure if we're using css_styled_content. Do you have any ideas where the configuration issue might be? Perhaps an 'arbitrarily disobey CSS rules' box that I can untick somewhere? : ) Thanks again for your help – I'm kind of new to Typo3!

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions

1) You can edit the HTML (there is a button "<>" to show the HTML view). Edit all elements and set the width accordingly. You need some HTML knowhow.

2) Use only one content element with only one table, so the cells are aligned properly. It is more work then 1), but if you need to add another entry someone, it will be easier.

3) Use an extension like tt_address to edit content and render it, or just create your own table and render it via TypoScript or f.e. "browser" extension. So you will have the content in an specific table and define then how the content should be rendered via Templates or TypoScript.

I would prefer 3), as it would be not more work as 1) or 2) if you know, how to do it. If you want to learn TYPO3, just fix the content via 1) or 2) and then implement it via 3) :)